# Accidentally clicked "Requires editing" on an obvious spam in "Triage"

Tags: discussion, triage

I have accidentally clicked the **Requires editing** button instead of **Unsalvageable** while reviewing **Triage**  tasks, so I failed the obvious test. While I didn't get put on hold for now, my 4-day just expired yesterday. I would really like to continue doing review tasks to help the community.

How should I go on? Will the effect of this mistake wear off over time or am I screwed for a while? Is there anything I can do (apart from being more careful of course).

Comment: Been there, done that. I recently clicked "leave open" on a question that should've been closed because the cursor wasn't where I thought it was. (just went back and cast a manual vote). It'll only affect you if you repeatedly make mistakes - specifically, the review bans will get longer every time you get banned. It doesn't affect your review, but you might find yourself banned faster if you fail an audit, so if it's a bad one, flag for mod attention and explain that and you might have the ban lifted. Meta is also an option though, but I personally prefer flags.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the suggestions. I feel bad because I mostly mess up the "Late answer" reviews because I don't find some of those trivials. This case hurts because how obvious it was. I'll try to be more careful from now on.

Comment: @Zoe why don't you make it an answer rather than comment?

Comment: Just one more question: do the ban intervals ever reset to the default or do they keep increasing forever?

Comment: @pappbence96 The ban interval will reset after you've not been banned for 30 consecutive days if I remember right

Comment: @pappbence96 have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287296/191185

Comment: Right... I've had a look over your reviews and while some aren't terrific choices, you're on the right track... You seem to be honest here in asking and concerned about your mistake, so what I've done is lift the review ban, but what I've not done is reset the timer on it - so if you fail another audit in 30 days, it's going to double to 16... I think that's a fair compromise... If you're unsure, you're always welcome to skip.

Comment: I am grateful for that, @JonClements. I hope I can further improve my choices in the future.